# What setting in M365 would prevent a user from being able to use Add-Ins for Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

A number of our users are unable to use Add-Ins for Outlook.  They're the modern type add-in that should work both in the web browser and in Outlook desktop client.

There's a button in Outlook labelled **Manage Add-ins** that takes you to https://outlook.office.com/mail/inclientstore, except the list of add-ins doesn't appear for affected users, like add-ins are disabled for them.

It's not PC or browser specific - it seems to be specific to the users/M365 accounts, as some of the affected users have had new laptops and the issue follows them like the plague.

My feeling it that there's an obscure setting that's been changed for these users, perhaps using Powershell and it's just come to light that whatever it is blocks these new add-ins.

Comment: We'll need more information about how the affected users differ, such as do they have distinct user accounts for M365 or a company account, do they use different security software, is this inside a domain etc.

Comment: @harrymc, the users have M365 work accounts.  They're running the same security software (Defender).  They're on the same domain.  We even have people within the same department where new employees can use modern add-ins, but older users with the same policies applies cannot.

Comment: You could try on the affected computers to [Uninstall Office from a PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) using the [uninstall support tool](https://aka.ms/SaRA-officeUninstallFromPC), reboot and install again. This might get rid of such settings. Question: Is there another common denominator for the affected computers, such as computer model, CPU model, TPM version etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Exchange admin centre** under **Recipients > Mailboxes** (https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/#/mailboxes/)  click the user to open the user pane and navigate to the Mailbox tab.  Check which **Role assignment policy** is applied to the user under **Mailbox policies**.

Duplicate or open a new tab.  In **Exchange Admin Centre** under **Roles > User Roles** (https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/#/userroles), find the policy that is applied to the mailbox.  Edit the permissions and check that the **My Custom Apps** and **My Marketplace Apps** are enabled (as appropriate for your environment).

Alternatively, change the role assignment policy that is assigned to the mailbox to a more appropriate policy.

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/add-ins-for-outlook/specify-who-can-install-and-manage-add-ins
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions-exo/role-assignment-policies

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible settings in M365 that might prevent users from using the Outlook add-in. Some of them are:

1.The user doesn't have the appropriate license or subscription to use the add-in.

2.Your administrator has disabled the Office Store for your organization, which prevents users from getting add-ins from the Store.

3.The add-in hasn't been deployed or assigned to a user or group by an admin administrator, or the add-in has been turned off or removed from the admin center.

4.The user has disabled the add-in from the Manage Add-ins page in Outlook or Outlook Web App.

5.The add-in is not compatible with the user's Outlook or browser version.
References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-addins-in-the-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-an-add-in-on-in-outlook-for-windows-f2ec3c07-59ce-4fd4-912d-460aa0bd009d

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-manage-and-install-add-ins-for-microsoft-365-programs-16278816-1948-4028-91e5-76dca5380f8d

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: Hi @Soki,
1. The users have M365 Business Premium license, same as unaffected users.
2. Office store works for unaffected users.  Office store doesn't work in Outlook for affected users, though the Get add-ins button does appear to work in Word.
3. The add-in was deployed/assigned by an admin user.
4. The affected users don't seem to be able to browse, add or use ANY Outlook add-in.
5. They're running the latest version of Outlook, same version as other users not experiencing the issue.